# Regex for matching phrase between '' php

Tags: php, regex

I want to match the content inside the `'` and `'` (single quotes). For example: `'for example'` should return `for` and `example`. It's only a part of the sentence I have to analyze, I used `preg_split(\s)` for the whole sentence, so the `'for example'` will become `'for and example'`.

Right now I've tried `/^'(.*)|(.*)'$/` and it only returns `for` but not the `example`, if I put it like `/^(.*)'|'(.*)$/`, it only returns `example` but not `for`. How should I fix this?

Comment: Well, matching between quotes is a solved issue, use `preg_match_all("~'([^']+)'~", $text, $matches)` and grab`$matches[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid double handling of the string by leveraging the `\G` metacharacter to continue matching an unlimited number of space-delimited strings inside of single quotes.

Code: ([PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/iWFn8)) ([Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/N5ZaUf/1/))

```
$string = "text 'for an example of the \"continue\" metacharacter' text";

var_export(preg_match_all("~(?|'|\G(?!^) )\K[^ ']+~", $string, $out) ? $out[0] : []);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'for',
  1 => 'an',
  2 => 'example',
  3 => 'of',
  4 => 'the',
  5 => '"continue"',
  6 => 'metacharacter',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the single sentences (which you then want to split) you can use [preg_match_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to capture anything between two single quotes.

```php
preg_match_all("~'([^']+)'~", $text, $matches)
$string = $matches[1];
```

`$string` now contains something like "example string with words".
Now if you want to split a string according to a specific sequence / character, you can make use of [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```php
$string = "example string with words";
$result = explode(" ", $string);
print_r($result);
```

gives you:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => example
    [1] => string
    [2] => with
    [3] => words
)
```